# When to use enum in java?

Tags: java, enums

I have approximately 30 resources each having approximately 10 attributes. I want to store some information about each attribute.

Example:

- It's multiplicity
- It RW (Read/Write) RO (Read only)
- longName
- shortname

So I was thinking of storing it in a Enum like this:

```
public enum Attributes {

    U_RESOURCETYPE(true, "RW", "resourceType", "rt"),
    U_RESOURCEID(false, "RO", "resourceID","ri"),
    //...
}
```

But this lead to 300 constants (30 resources * 10 attributes).

I could also use a config file or a Singleton Enum with a Map as member.

What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Why cannot use database instead of overhead into code?

Comment: Persist to a database or to file, using a solid (de-)serialization library.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way is to use a file that stores your information, it can be a xml file, some dat file or even a database because you want to store and retrive data not logical states.

Enum is really useful when you want to control objects' states. For example, a smartphone user can be still, running, in a car or walking, so it is interesting to use a enum as a collection of states. However it can also be reached using a Class with public static variables.

Here is an example https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity